# visibleCells returns all cells in a collectionView in a tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I created a [custom UITableViewCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptTb7.png) that contains a collectionView. This custom cell conforms to UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDataSource protocols and manages the collectionView.

But when I use this custom cell in a tableView, the visibleCells property of my collectionView returns all 20 cells even though there are only 3 cells that are visible on the screen.

This leads to a situation where my collectionView does not reuse cells because it thinks all of it cells are visible on the screen and causes memory problems.

Here is my implementation in tableViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "org.cocoapods.*****") else { return }
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CampaignCollectionViewContainerCell", bundle: bundle), forCellReuseIdentifier: "campaignContainerCellIdentifier")
}

.
.
.

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "campaignContainerCellIdentifier") as? CampaignCollectionViewContainerCell else { fatalError() }
    return cell
}
```

I tried changing the visibleCells property but it is get-only.

I guess it doesn't matter but my custom UITableViewCell is in a private pod and the UITableViewController is in my main project that uses this pod.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue before when embed collection view inside table view cell , here you are my solution to check if specific cell is visible for user or not

This solution it works perfectly for this case (embedded collection / table )

Note: You can make array called "visibleCells" and fill it by loop on your all cells and add visible one to this array:

```
let cellRect = YourCell.contentView.convert(YourCell.contentView.bounds, to: UIScreen.main.coordinateSpace)
if UIScreen.main.bounds.intersects(cellRect) {
     print("This cell is visible")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you returning the correct data for 
`numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` and 
`numberOfItemsInSection`

Comment: Yes I'm returning the count of my datasource.